# How can write SQL command in string format

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I convert this code:

```
SELECT * FROM DB
WHERE field LIKE N'%'+RTRIM(LTRIM('98'))+N'%'
```

to:

```
SET @stringWhere= ' SELECT * FROM DB AND field LIKE '+N'%' +RTRIM(LTRIM(@field))+ N'%';
```

Comment: That isn't what you want to do at all. You should NEVER build up a string like that. You should use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection. And of course the desired string you are asking for is not valid as there is no where clause.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Consider reviewing [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And as @SeanLange suggested, read up on [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Hello, Masi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  As currently written your question is not clear, and may get closed.  Don't give up.  Improve your question so that it can be easily understood and you'll find that those close votes will be removed.

Comment: Do you want to know, that single quotes have to be doubled to escape them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answer my question, If I want to set SELECT command in SQL with string format we can use:

```
SET @stringWhere= 'SELECT * FROM DB AND field LIKE '+'N''%'+ RTRIM(LTRIM(@field))+'%'''+' ' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of guessing here. Please the code below. And make sure you look at the comments in the code as there are several things that could use improvement.

```
declare @field nvarchar(10) = N'98'

select * --don't use *, select ONLY the columns you need
from DB
where Name like '%' + @field+ '%' --be careful here, this is a nonSARGable predicate with the leading wildcard. As such all indexes will be rendered useless.
```